# How to print the names of predicted classes in Neural Network using keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am using a pre-trained model in keras and ended up predicting the class indices to be some integer values, but I don't seem to understand how do I print the names those classes?

The model I am using is ResNet 50.

Comment: what data set are you using

Comment: @maz I am not using any dataset, the  model is already trained. I don't need a dataset to train it.

Comment: So it depends on what you are doing. If you are using the standard pre trained model for exactly the same application you should look up what was the original class table. As you are using resnet-50 I imagine it was trained with the imagenet dataset, so you would need a dictionary (or a list or whatever) to look that up. For the case of imagenet I found this pickled dictionary: https://gist.github.com/yrevar/6135f1bd8dcf2e0cc683. Look that up

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://martin-thoma.com/image-classification/

The key part is:

```
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
```

Comment: Worked after replacing `from imagenet_utils` with `from keras.applications.imagenet_utils`

Comment: Also, this is only designed for the 1000 classes used by ImageNet. It won't work if your classes are different.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using imagenet data but retrain on your own set: When using keras' `flow_from_directory` of an `ImageDataGenerator`, it conveniently saves the labels of your folders in a `dict` accessible within `.class_indices`! The values of the dict correspond to the positions of your `model.predict` output.

Crude example:

```
preds = model.predict(x)
for cls in training_generator.class_indices:
    print(cls+": "+preds[0][training_generator.class_indices[cls]])
```

See also: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/