# Process special JSON with keys as numbers

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract data from [file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a/raw/238f720ff059c1f82f368259d1ca4ffa5dd8f9f5/imagenet1000_clsidx_to_labels.txt) into a dictionary via `json.loads`. Example:

```
{725: 'pitcher, ewer',
726: "plane, carpenter's plane, woodworking plane"}
```

1. `json.loads` can't handle the keys as numbers
2. Some values are "" and others are '.

Any suggestions?

**Code**

```
import requests

url = url
r = requests.get(url)
response = r.text.replace('\n','')
response = re.sub(r':(\d+):*', r'"\1"', response)
```

Comment: The file in that URL is not valid JSON (and it doesn't claim that it is). You can use a more flexible parser, such as https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you supplied seems like a valid Python `dict`, so I suggest an alternative approach, with `literal_eval`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval(r.text)
print(data[726])
```

Output: `plane, carpenter's plane, woodworking plane`

---

If you still like `json`, then you can try replacing the numbers with strings using regex.

```
import re

s = re.sub(r"(?m)^(\W*)(\d+)\b", r'\1"\2"', r.text)
data = json.loads(s)
```